# Update guidance for How To Answer to improve answer quality?

Tags: feature-request, answer-quality

I was thinking there has been a lot of focus on low-quality questions lately on meta, however I have also been seeing a lot of low-quality answers.

Most people using the site probably learn from example. If the majority of what they see is low-quality answers, then they are much more likely to post low-quality answers too, which in turn begs for more low-quality questions.

So with that in mind, can we update the existing guidance for how to answer with some short pointers on what we consider to be a good and acceptable answer on this site?

I will post my own suggestions below, however the existing guidance for posting an answer is this:

> #### Your Answer
>
> Thanks for contributing an answer to Stack Overflow!
>
> - Please be sure to *answer the question*. Provide details and share your research!
>
> But *avoid* …
>
> - Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers.
> - Making statements based on opinion; back them up with references or personal experience.
>
> To learn more, see our [tips on writing great answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: "Easy" questions (which I suspect are in the majority?) encourage [Fastest Gun in the West](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/163250) low-quality answers (e.g. one line link to off-site resource, or code dumps with little explanation). Sure, improving the guidance might help a little, but my guess is that most people will just ignore it anyways.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to see something that explicitly **asks the user to explain their answer**, and asks them **not to provide a code-only answer**.

The goal here is to make the internet a better place by providing a good resource for programmers to get excellent answers from other programmers, and not to become a fast community debugging service.

Perhaps something like this:

> #### Your Answer
>
> Thanks for contributing an answer to Stack Overflow!
>
> Please be sure to
>
> - Answer the question being asked.
> - Explain your answer. A solution is good, but a solution with an explanation is great!
> - Back up your answer with references or personal experience.
>
> But *avoid* …
>
> - Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers.
> - Making statements based on opinion only.
> - Providing an answer that contains nothing more than a block of code or a link.
>
> To learn more, see our [tips on writing great answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: On the whole, I think your copy is better than the original.  I think it's worth considering replacing the original text on that basis alone.  I do believe, however, that it will only have a modest effect, for the reasons specified by Cupcake in his comment below the question.

Comment: That said, I'm a firm believer in consequences.  "Bad" behavior is fixed, not by providing more explanation, but by making that bad behavior hurt.  It's not more information that these folks need, it's convincing them to leave their bad forum habits behind.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah, I have no great illusions that this will magically fix the quality problems, but I do hope its a step towards educating the users a bit more about what we want on the site. I'm a firm believer that most people want to do "the right thing", and just need to be educated about what is considered "right" for this site.

Comment: What about an additional point of mentioning better alternatives to what the OP has comitted to doing / pointing out additional hazards? Shouldn't that be an additional bullet point there? Because I somehow doubt everyone (including me) would read all that into "Explain your answer".

Comment: @Deduplicator I'd want to keep the list of bullets very short and easy to skim through, and think that would add too much text. Also, people are quite happy to comment on those things anyways, so am not sure it would be needed.